# Storing an std::assume_aligned pointer C++ 20

Tags: c++, traits, simd, c++20, memory-alignment

In C++ 20 we're getting assume aligned, this would be very usefull for audio code where pointers to aligned blocks of floats are passed around all the time. Let's say we have the following span type:

```
template<typename T>
struct Signal
{
    const T* data
    size_t size;
};
```

How would one indicate that the data pointer in this struct is aligned by some constexpr integer? Is something like this already possible in C++ 20?

```
constexpr int SIMDAlignment = 16;

template<typename T>
struct Signal
{
    aligned<SIMDAlignment> const T* data
    size_t size;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the *assume-aligned* hint is a property of a particular pointer object, and it cannot be made a property of a pointer type. However, you might try to wrap that pointer by an (inline) getter function and use `std::assume_aligned` for its return value. For example, in my experiment, when I used the pointer returned by such a function, it was treated as "aligned" (pointing to aligned data) correctly by GCC:

```
double* f()
{
  static double* data =
    (double*)std::aligned_alloc(64, 1024 * sizeof(double));
  return std::assume_aligned<64>(data);
}

void g()
{
  double* a = f();
  for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    a[i] = 123.45;
}
```

In this case, the array was filled by `vmovapd` which requires aligned memory access.

On the contrary, when I changed:

```
return std::assume_aligned<64>(data);
```

to:

```
return data;
```

The generated assembly contained `vmovupd` which works with unaligned data.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/d5aPPj — check the `.L19` loop in both cases.

Comment: That makes sense, from the name it's not surprising that it's just a `std` version of GNU C `void *__builtin_assume_aligned(void*, size_t)`.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html  (Used like `foo = __builtin_assume_aligned(foo, 64);` in C where implicit conversion to/from void* is allowed.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes; even the corresponding proposal mentions a possible implementation by `__builtin_assume_aligned` for GCC and Clang: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1007r3.pdf.

Comment: In GNU C, you can sometimes do stuff like `typedef int aligned_int __attribute__((aligned(16)))` and have pointers to that type, but that's separate.  (And doesn't work that easily because sizeof(aligned_int) is also 16, with padding).  The typedef trick works better for declaring *under*-aligned and `may_alias` versions of types.